# How can I find all files in a directory with illegal characters in the file name?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, posix

Here is what I prepared and where I got stuck:

```
find / \! -name "*[:alnum:]*" -type f -ls > ~/Desktop/files_not-allowed-char.txt
```

I actually want to list all files which include one of these characters:

```
\ / : * ? " < > |
```

The other way around: I want to list all files which have other characters in the name than:

```
[A-Z][a-z][0-9]äöüÄÖÜß_-.()#[]
or in other "words":
[:alnum:] and "äöüÄÖÜß_-.()#[]"
```

I hope I could clarify my wishes. I am entering unknown territory...

Thanks in advance!

---

Background info:
I want to change from AFP to SMB but have to make sure that I rename all invalid file and folder names (e.g. `invalid_Directory_Name./` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ! in front of "*[:alnum:]*" will negate any file that has a character in [:alnum:] so it will only match file names which ONLY have non alphanumeric characters.

You could use a different regex to find punctuation `find . -name "*[:punct:]"` but that includes characters you don't care about. `find . -name "*[\/:*?"<>|]*"` should match anything with at least one of those characters in the brackets. (though you probably need to escape a few of them :) )

Comment: This helped a lot... `find /volume1 -name "*[\+\{\;\"\\\=\?~\(\)\<\>\&\*\|\$]*" -ls -type f > /volume1/volume1-file_not-allowed-char.txt` is my solution.